# Use add_action to run a script, but only on the post editor page

Tags: javascript, hooks, actions, post-editor

My JS script runs on every page, but I want it to run only on the post editor page.

```
function sm_validate_title() {
        echo "
        <script>
        console.log('script working')
        ...code to validate title and content
        </script>";
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'sm_validate_title_client_side');
```

Maybe I should try a different hook? or add some condition on the callback function? I don't know really which hook would work, there are so many, and no idea also on how to check if page == post page with JS.

Comment: The classic editor or the block editor?

Comment: On the right I can see "Post" and "Block" tabs, so I'm guessing it's a block editor?

Answer (score 0):

The function get_current_screen gets the current screen object.

I used a condition inside my callback function to return a script only if the screen id == post:

```
if( $currentScreen->id === "post" ) {
        echo "
        <script>
        </script>";
    }
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/